# Convert Valve data structure to JSON

Tags: python, json

I have a data structure that looks quite similar to JSON:

```
"items"
{
    "first"
    {
        "a"     "1"
        "b"     "2"
        "c"     "3"
        "d"     "4"
        "e"     "5"
    }
    "second"
    {
        "f"     "6"
        "g"     "7"
        "h"     "8"
        "i"     "9"
        "j"     "10"
    }
}
```

But the problem is that this format does not work with JSON parser. Is there any method in Python where you can convert this format to a JSON format to manage my data? I have tried using `json.loads(json.dumps(data))` and it does not work. When searching for data inside this format using i.e. `jsonObj['items']` it shows me `TypeError: string indices must be integers`.

My aim is to get something along the lines of this:

```
"items" :
{
    "first" :
    {
        "a" : "1",
        "b" : "2",
        "c" : "3",
        "d" : "4",
        "e" : "5"
    },
    "second" :
    {
        "f" : "6",
        "g" : "7",
        "h" : "8",
        "i" : "9",
        "j" : "10"
    }
}
```

Comment: When you say "data structure", what you do you mean? This doesn't look like a Python `dict`. Do you literally have a string containing this?

Comment: This isn't JSON, so why would you expect a JSON parser to parse it?

Comment: Yes, i read this exact string from a file and my aim is to convert it to JSON format.

Comment: Where does that file come from? It would be helpful to know if this format has a name. It would be even _more_ helpful if whatever is creating it can be convinced to output JSON :-). Also, please [edit] your question to show what the intended result is. There isn't a single clear, unambiguous mapping between what you're showing us and JSON. E.g., it looks like `{}` is being used both for things that might end up as arrays and for things that might end up as objects in JSON. And arrays don't have names, so what should "items" become? A key in an object whose value is an array?

Comment: I've read that sometimes JSON parser in Python can make corrections and convert it to JSON without any issues. My source was incorrect it seems like.

Comment: Chris, it just has a .txt extension.

Comment: The extension is irrelevant. A `.txt` file can contain literally anything. I'm asking whether this format has a name, even if it's just "proprietary output format from tool X".

Comment: It looks like the data format used by some Valve games, if memory serves.

Comment: You haven't described what the input data should look like converted to JSON format.

Comment: AKX, it is indeed retrieved from a Valve game. Any idea how would you go about converting it to JSON?

Comment: I think you added the commas to the wrong example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Happily, the atoms used by [the format](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/KeyValues) are similar enough to Python that we can use the `tokenize` and `ast` modules for an ad-hoc parser.

It will probably break horribly on broken input, but works for your example data :)

```py
import tokenize
import token
import ast
import io
import json


def parse_valve_format(data):
    dest = {}
    stack = [dest]
    for tok in tokenize.tokenize(io.BytesIO(data.encode()).readline):
        if tok.type == token.STRING:
            ts = ast.literal_eval(tok.string)
            if isinstance(stack[-1], str):
                # already a string on the stack?
                # this has to be a key-value setting
                key = stack.pop(-1)
                stack[-1][key] = ts
            else:
                # otherwise assume we'll find a } soon
                stack.append(ts)
        elif tok.type == token.OP and tok.string == "{":
            obj = {}
            key = stack.pop(-1)
            stack[-1][key] = obj
            stack.append(obj)
        elif tok.type == token.OP and tok.string == "}":
            assert isinstance(stack[-1], dict), "stray }"
            stack.pop(-1)
    return dest


result_dict = parse_valve_format(
    """
"items"
{
    "first"
    {
        "a"     "1"
        "b"     "2"
        "c"     "3"
        "d"     "4"
        "e"     "5"
    }
    "second"
    {
        "f"     "6"
        "g"     "7"
        "h"     "8"
        "i"     "9"
        "j"     "10"
    }
}
"""
)

print(json.dumps(result_dict, indent=2))
```

output:

```
{
  "items": {
    "first": {
      "a": "1",
      "b": "2",
      "c": "3",
      "d": "4",
      "e": "5"
    },
    "second": {
      "f": "6",
      "g": "7",
      "h": "8",
      "i": "9",
      "j": "10"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't JSON data.

JSON data is in the format

```
{
   "foo" : "bar"
   "sample2": {
                 "key1: value
              }
}
```

Your data isn't stored this way, not in the JSON format at least, and hence JSON Parse functions will not work.

Now coming to the JSON Parser, it can sometimes make corrections, for missing keys or values, but in your case, it appears as though it does not understand what is going on.

Your best bet would be to use a little bit of Regex Magic to turn this into a JSON Format and proceed from there.

Answer (score 0):

You can roll your own parser/transpiler. Here's one that only works for the example you gave. (e.g. doesn't work with tokens that contain spaces, or with lists/numbers/etc.)

```
def match_str(s):
    return len(s) >= 2 and s[0] == '"' and s[-1] == '"'

def match_terminal(s):
    return s == "{" or s == "}"

def notjsonstr_to_jsonstr(s):
    tokens = s.split()
    xs = []
    was_terminal = True
    was_str = False

    for token in tokens:
        if len(xs) != 0 and xs[-1] == "}" and token != "}":
            xs.append(",")
        if match_terminal(token):
            if was_str:
                xs.append(":")
            xs.append(token)
            was_terminal = True
            was_str = False
            continue
        if match_str(token):
            if was_str:
                xs.append(":")
            elif not was_terminal:
                xs.append(",")
            xs.append(token)
            was_str = not was_str
        else:
            raise Exception("Unexpected token")
        was_terminal = False

    return "".join(xs)
```

This is of course very flawed, works only with a very limited grammar, and would probably make any parser writer wrinkle their nose.

Comment: Thanks i will try this. Every single value in the file that i am trying to parse is in quotes (string) so this might actually work.

Comment: @JaCkSoN There's some problems with it currently. Check back in a bit.

Comment: @JaCkSoN OK, I think it's ready for a test run.